# Sharing rule on Detail object

Tags: sharing, master-detail

Lets take we have 2 objects '**Invoice**' and '**InvoiceLineItems**'.
 Both are in **Master Detail relationship**. 
 At OWD Level i kept the **Private** for Invoice.
 We have a requirement as follows.

I want to share the specific set of 'InvoiceLineitems' to the user based on certain criteria.

Now i want to share only Invoice LineItem record which are meeting the following criteria
**Status ='Approved' and StartDate =Today and EndDate=Today**

**I cant create a sharing rule for detail records as its in MD relationship.**
How can we achieve it? Somebody please help me out

Comment: I'd question if these need to be on the same invoice.

Answer (score 1):

***In case of Master Detail:***

Yes you cant create sharing rule on detail side of the object.Child objects don’t have a share-record of their own and will be shared along with the master record.

***In case of Lookup:***

Child objects can have their own sharing access level and ownership. Sharing access through hierarchies can also be disabled.

so simple solution is change the relationship better You can make it Lookup relationship (it depends!!!)